# Disable double buffering entirely or render cursor without double buffering in OS X?

Tags: macos, mouse, graphics, opengl, framebuffer

Currently, in OS X, the entire system is drawn using [double buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics) through [Quartz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_Compositor). The purpose of this is, as far as I know, to eliminate [screen tearing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing).

The reason I would like double buffering to be disabled is because of the mouse lag that it creates, and I am absolutely certain that double buffering is the root cause of all mouse lag in OS X (other than mouse acceleration, which I have disabled by using Razer's proprietary mouse drivers with my Razer DeathAdder).

If I boot OS X with an unsupported video card, the entire OS becomes very laggy, because QE/CI is not supported on the video card and is therefore disabled. However, double buffering is *also* disabled when I do this, as I can see screen tearing when I shake windows or move the mouse quickly. When boot this way, and double buffering is disabled, the mouse is *perfect*, just like it is on Windows. No input delay, no acceleration, just raw mouse movement.

I want to know how either double-buffering can be disabled across the entire system, or maybe even if there is a way to draw the mouse outside of Quartz, so that it is not double buffered.

Comment: I've never seen mouse lag of any kind on any graphics system Apple has shipped. Which exact model Mac is this on? (Include your "MacProX,Y" model identifier from System Profiler / System Information). What happens when you use the graphics card that Apple built into your Mac?

Comment: This is the strange thing. Most people who have used a Mac for a while say "no, I don't notice any mouse lag." Yet, anyone I know who's coming from Windows and plays a lot of FPS games (and therefore would notice the input delay) and tries a Mac, they notice it right away. I absolutely assure you that there is input delay. Not lag as in framerate lag, but delay. 32 milliseconds, to be exact. I have a MacPro3,1. Read more about this here: http://d43.me/blog/1205/the-cause-for-all-your-mac-os-x-mouse-annoyances/ . I'm not the only one.

Comment: Mouse pointers are usually hardware based and rendered kinda like an old school sprite. So the problem might be in how/when the registers/memory for the hardware mouse pointer are being updated when Quartz is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to disable is `Beam Sync`. This can be disabled through Quartz Debugger, an application that is part of the Xcode Developer Tools.

More information can be found here: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=779950

(Note: Take the above with a grain of salt. I do not own a Mac and found that nearly 3 year old forum thread with Google. There are more recent threads though, just none as detailed).

Comment: Almost! Disabling Beam Sync did seem to disable double buffering for everything... except the cursor (which is the problem for me). This is still very helpful though! If there's a way to disable double buffering for the cursor as well, then this would be awesome.

Comment: @Huskehn: I don't think the cursor is separately double-buffered. I'm not even sure what that means :D

Answer (score 1):

It seems Pro Tools starting with version 8 has an issue with Beam Sync. Basically it's a form of double buffering that OSX uses when drawing Quartz windows.

- Get a preferences pane called `Secrets`.
- Open Secrets and go to the System settings.
- Look for Beam Sync and set it to disable.
- Set Enable Quartz Extreme to On.
- Reboot.

While running Pro Tools (and having the screen redraw slowly), you open this app, press `Cmd+1`, and disable Beam Sync and ensure that Quartz Extreme is On. You will immediately notice a perfectly smoove and beautifully working Pro Tools.

Rather than having to open Quartz Debug every time you run Pro Tools however, `Secrets` is the easiest way to set the OSX preference for this semi-permanently. For some reason however, the preference for Beam Sync occasionally gets set back to `Automatic` and you need to reset it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work like it does with Quartz Debugger. The settings revert once I restart (I did press "Update Secrets"). Note that I'm on Mountain Lion.